# Error al retornar valor dentro de un bloque Try y Catch C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

Tengo el siguiente método el cual me sirve para transformar un arreglo de `bytes` a una imagen y re tornándola posteriormente.

```
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);

        return Image.FromStream(ms);

    }
```

Quiero colocar un bloque `try catch` haciéndolo de la siguiente manera.

```
     public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {


        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        try
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Pero al hacer esto me da un error el cual me indica que no se retorna un valor ya que en el bloque "Catch" no se esta retornando nada.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo hacer uso del "Try Catch" en mi método sin que me genere el error anteriormente mencionado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer uso del "Try Catch" en mi método sin que me genere
>   el error anteriormente mencionado?

Simplemente declarando una variable del tipo que retorna el método [Image.FromStream()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.0) (Image) antes del bloque `try{} catch{}`,

Debe tener en cuenta `inicializar` la variable antes del `try{} catch{}`, si lo hace dentro del `try{}` obtendrá un error de variable no asignada. [Documentación de try{} catch{}](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    Image imagen = null; // importante inicializar la variable

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    try
    {
        imagen = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
  return imagen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deberías hacer primero es poner una variable para primero enviarle el "Image.FromStream(ms);" y luego retorna la variable pero al ultimo , osea después del catch:

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
   byte[] imagen;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    try
    {
     imagen=   Image.FromStream(ms);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
 return imagen;
}
```

Comment: Intente de esta manera y específicamente en esta línea de código "imagen =   Image.FromStream(ms);"  al asignarle a mi variable el Image.FromStream(ms) me lanza un error: "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Drawing.Image' en 'byte[]'

Comment: @Sasori1264 esto es porque el método [FromStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.0),  retorna un tipo [Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.0), deberá declarar la variable de este tipo, algo así quizá. `Image imagen = null;`